# Angular 9 "Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'. "

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-file-upload

I have this problem when i am trying to display selected image before upload image

[image]

> **company.component.ts**

```
handleFileInput(file: File){

    console.log(file);

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.onload = event => {
      this.imageUrl = event.target.result;
      console.log(this.imageUrl);
    };

  }
```

> HTML

```
<input
  type="file"
  #fileInput
  (change)="handleFileInput(fileInput.files[0])"
/>

<img [src]="imageUrl" height="50px" alt="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an example of how it might be implemented:

**Component:**

```js
public imageUrl : SafeResourceUrl;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

public upload(list: FileList): void {
  const urlToBlob = window.URL.createObjectURL(list.item(0)) 
  this.imageUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(urlToBlob); 
}
```

**Template:**

```html
<input type="file" (change)="upload($event.target.files)">

<img [src]="url">
```

Comment: do you mean this.imageUrl is public url: SafeResourceUrl; ??

Comment: thanks yes its work..but i have question your code is different... i saw a lot of implementations and all same and does not work on my app...but your code is worked why ?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of implementations you saw

Comment: its like my example that i wrote it in this question they all using this implementation  

   ` if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {

        this.imageFile = event.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        reader.onload = () => {
          this.url = reader.result;
              this.dtr.detectChanges();

        }; `

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(
    private dtr: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ){
    
  }
handleFileInput(event) {

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {

        this.imageFile = event.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        reader.onload = () => {
          this.url = reader.result;
              this.dtr.detectChanges();

        };
      }
```

in Html file.

```
 <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" (change)="handleFileInput($event)"> 

<img [src]="url">
```